# how to turn string representation of a byte into a byte

Tags: java

I have a String that holds the string representation of a byte value.

```
String string = "0xOA";
```

how do I turn this into a byte with the value 0A?

Comment: Did you mean your string to have "0A" rather than "OA"?

Comment: No - I want a byte primitive with the value 0A (or an int with the value 10 that I can cast to a byte)

Comment: My point is that you've got a letter "O" instead of the digit "0" in your sample string. Surely that's not intentional, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.decode("0x0A");
```

This works for strings in octal and decimal. The reason for using Integer is that `0xFF` will fail for Byte (as 255 > 127)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Byte.parseByte(string.substring(2), 16)
```

The `.substring(2)` is to get rid of the `0x`, and 16 is the radix for hexadecimals.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Byte.valueOf(String s)` ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if I try it directly byte b = Byte.valueOf("0X0A"); I get a NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
Byte.valueOf(string, 16);
```

Comment: Same as above - NumberFormatException